# What is difference between sjlj vs dwarf vs seh?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mingw, cpu-architecture, mingw-w64

I can't find enough information to decide which compiler should I use to compile my project. There are several programs on different computers simulating a process. On Linux, I'm using GCC. Everything is great. I can optimize code, it compiles fast and uses not-so-much memory.

I do my own benchmark with MSVC and GCC compilers. Later one produces slightly faster binaries (for each subarchitecture). Though compile time is much more than MSVC.

So I decided to use MinGW. But can't find any explanation about exception handling methods and their implementations in MinGW. I can use different distributions for different operating systems and architectures.

Considerations:

- Compile time and memory are not important for my usage. Only important thing is runtime optimization. I need my programs to be fast enough. A slow compiler is acceptable.
- OS: Microsoft Windows XP / 7 / 8 / Linux
- Architecture: Intel Core i7 / Core2 / and a very old i686 running XP :P

Comment: I'm surprised gcc produces faster code than MSVC; things must have changed in the last few years...

Comment: @trojanfoe I've been told so many times to use MSVC instead of MinGW. Everybody thinks msvc is faster! I tested MinGW 7.2 and MSVC 2010. with a simple cpu-burst program. On corei7 with `-O3 -mtune=corei7` GCC is 45% faster than MSVC

Comment: In my own experience, with a chess move generator (which used bitboards), both MSVC and Intel C++ were 10% quicker than gcc, but that was 2 year ago...

Comment: @sorush-r just to be sure what "45% faster" means: 1.45 times as fast as MSVC?

Comment: @Wolf In that time 45% faster meant 45% less time to execute for me. If I remember correctly, execution time of our molecular geometry modelling software was 134s (gcc) and 194s (msvc) for a specific test. Nevertheless now I consider my method of measurement  to be incorrect and insufficient (:

Comment: @sorush-r I see, you calculated (194-134)/134 which is near 45%, thanks.

Comment: I think this will depend on the workload and what specific optimizations will/can be applied by a compiler under the circumstances. I had one example where a gruesome boost::spirit grammar ran very quickly on MSVC but the gcc's executable performance was less than stellar. That was a few years ago.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

There's a short overview at [MinGW-w64 Wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Exception%20Handling/):

> **Why doesn't mingw-w64 gcc support Dwarf-2 Exception Handling?**
>
> The **Dwarf-2 EH** implementation for Windows is not designed at all to
>   work under 64-bit Windows applications. In win32 mode, the exception
>   unwind handler cannot propagate through non-dw2 aware code, this means
>   that any exception going through any non-dw2 aware "foreign frames"
>   code will fail, including Windows system DLLs and DLLs built with
>   Visual Studio. Dwarf-2 unwinding code in gcc inspects the x86
>   unwinding assembly and is unable to proceed without other dwarf-2
>   unwind information.
>
> The **SetJump LongJump** method of exception handling works for most
>   cases on both win32 and win64, except for general protection faults.
>   Structured exception handling support in gcc is being developed to
>   overcome the weaknesses of dw2 and sjlj. On win64, the
>   unwind-information are placed in xdata-section and there is the .pdata
>   (function descriptor table) instead of the stack. For win32, the chain
>   of handlers are on stack and need to be saved/restored by real
>   executed code.

[GCC GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/WindowsGCCImprovements) about *Exception Handling*:

> GCC supports two methods for exception handling (EH):
>
> - **DWARF-2 (DW2) EH**, which requires the use of DWARF-2 (or DWARF-3) debugging information. DW-2 EH can cause executables to be
>     slightly bloated because large call stack unwinding tables have to be
>     included in th executables.
> - A method based on **setjmp/longjmp (SJLJ)**. SJLJ-based EH is much slower than DW2 EH (penalising even normal execution when no
>     exceptions are thrown), but can work across code that has not been
>     compiled with GCC or that does not have call-stack unwinding
>     information.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Structured Exception Handling (SEH)**
>
> Windows uses its own exception handling mechanism known as Structured Exception Handling (SEH). *[...]*
>   Unfortunately, GCC does not support SEH yet. *[...]*

See also:

- [Exception handling models of GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318383/exception-handling-models-of-gcc)
- [C++ Exception Handling for IA-64](http://static.usenix.org/events/osdi2000/wiess2000/full_papers/dinechin/dinechin_html/)
- [EH newbies howto](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2002-07/msg00391.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm going to use DW2 for 32bit and SEH for 64. SEH is available in mingwbuilds (4.8). Should I wait for stable release of 4.8 or it's ok? It compiles here. I'm currently making dependencies of my project using 4.8 with SEH. No problems yet...

Comment: All dependencies (including Boost library, OpenSSL, ICU, freeGLUT) compiled but Qt end up with lots of internal compiler errors. I think I'll wait for stable release of 4.8

Comment: Did you use binaries of qt or did you compile by your own?

Comment: @woreos I use my own Qt build. I found that there was no problem with neither Qt nor GCC 4.8. It was my half-burned RAM! [1](http://superuser.com/questions/575482/install-windows-8-for-second-time-failed) Now everything works fine

Answer (score 97):

> **SJLJ** (setjmp/longjmp): – available for 32 bit and 64 bit – not “zero-cost”: even if an exception isn’t thrown, it incurs a minor
> performance penalty (~15% in exception heavy code) – allows exceptions
> to traverse through e.g. windows callbacks
>
> **DWARF** (DW2, dwarf-2) – available for 32 bit only – no permanent runtime overhead – needs whole call stack to be dwarf-enabled, which
> means exceptions cannot be thrown over e.g. Windows system DLLs.
>
> **SEH** (zero overhead exception) – will be available for 64-bit GCC 4.8.

*source: https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit*

Comment: Sorry, source link is added.

Comment: So now in 2016 we can put this question to rest and simply always use SEH.

Comment: @RustyX Only if your target is x86_64

Comment: So Dwarf for x86?