# How to build 64-bit MinGW Qt application on Windows (with Qt Creator)

Tags: windows, qt, 64-bit, mingw

I'm looking (and sure I am not the only one) for the most straight forward way to build MinGW based 64-bit Qt programs on Windows. Straight forward means minimal effort and time (e.g. for building and setting up). Currently I run the normal, official development environment of the qt-project.org website for Windows 32-bit with MinGW/OpenGL and QtCreator. Of course I have read the (unfinished...) 64 bit wiki page of qt-project.org and I also read through different stackoverflow questions, but still I'm confused. I know that the topic of how to build 64-bit Qt is treated in other posts, but this is not my question, what I need is an overview and the most favorable 64-bit MinGW port.

One thing that confused me for example was that the DLLs in "x64-Qt-5.2.1+QTCreator-3.0.1-(gcc-4.8.2-seh).7z" package from mingwbuilds sourceforge project seem to be 32-bit.

To clarify my question a bit let me also ask some related questions:

- Do I need to build a 64-bit development environment first to produce
  64-bit executables or can I keep my normal default environment and
  only exchange the MinGW toolchain with a 64-bit toolchain?
- Where can
  I get 64-bit Qt libraries for the deployment, or do I need to build
  them myself anyway? Or where can I get 64-bit development environment
  including the 64-bit libraries?
- If I have to build myself, which MinGW 64-bit port is the most favorable?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit - Any use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update 3/11/2019:** Starting with Qt 5.12 the Qt Project officially supports MinGW-w64 in 64-bit mode. You can install it from the Qt installer or build it yourself from Qt's sources (they've ironed out issues that were preventing successful builds).

**Prior update:** I think that [rubenvb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001073/1583123) is now the best answer to this question: MSYS2 contains an up-to-date Qt built with MinGW-w64, which is what you'll need to build 64-bit Qt apps. I recommend using the Qt wiki link in rubenvb's answer for deployment; it's greatly improved.

### Qt64-NG

I recommend installing your Qt build from the [Qt64-NG project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/).

The project provides an up-to-date, x64 Qt build with MinGW-w64. The MinGW-w64 project's GCC compiler is also included in the installer versions (but not in the 7z). You'll want the same version of GCC in MinGW-w64 that was used to build Qt for building your own apps, so I'd recommend choosing the installer.

You will need to choose a build with the exception stack frame unwinding method you want. The question [What is difference between sjlj vs dwarf vs seh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15670169/1583123) describes the differences between the types of exception handlers that are present in different builds of Qt. SJLJ was the only choice before GCC 4.8 was released, but later GCC versions support SEH. Either choice will work, though SEH is more efficient.

### Post-install

After you install Qt, you could add the Qt/qt-ver/qt-ver/bin and Qt/qt-ver/mingw64/bin directories to your User or System Path variable in your Environment Variables, which will allow you to use MinGW-w64's GCC for building from your preferred build process. Qt Creator will auto-detect MinGW-w64 as an installed compiler after you do this.

If you would rather not add to your path, you can specify the compiler for the version you just set up with Qt Creator, manually. You will likely need to add the Qt version by selecting qmake.exe under Options > Build & Run. You'll also want to select gdb.exe as your debugger under the Build & Run > Debuggers tab. It will be located at Qt/qt-ver/qt-ver/mingw64/bin.

You can exchange the MinGW-w64 toolchain with other toolchains. To do this in Qt Creator you can create and swap between kits.

### Deployment

You can use the Qt64-NG build for development and deployment. To deploy, you'll want to package the files your application will need to run with your application, so your end-user won't have to do any extra installation steps.

First, create a deployment folder (likely with your application name) and copy your application exe file to it. If you're using Qt Creator, you can find the path to your application exe either in the Projects tab on the side bar or in the application's .pro file if it is specified there.

There are two ways that you can copy the dll dependencies you'll need to run your application. You can either copy the needed files manually or you can use windeployqt, a program provided with your Qt installation that will automatically copy (most) needed dependencies for deployment to the application deploy folder you just created.

### Copy files manually

Copy the following dll files from your Qt/qt-ver/qt-ver/bin and Qt/qt-ver/mingw64/bin folders to your application deploy folder. Some dll files will be located in both folders, and either location is acceptable for use:

```
icudt54.dll
icuin54.dll
icuuc54.dll
libgcc_s_sjlj.dll or libgcc_s_seh.dll (corresponds with chosen stack unwinding method)
libssp-0.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
```

You'll also need to include any Qt5*.dll files that correspond with Qt modules you are using in your project.

Next, you'll need to copy any plugin dll files that Qt requires. Qt will look for plugins by default at application deploy folder/plugins. You can find the plugin folders you will want to copy at Qt/qt-ver/qt-ver/plugins. The exception to this is the platforms folder, which it will try to find at your application deploy directory/platforms. The following directory structure indicates where to copy files for a minimal project. Copy any other needed plugins including the containing folder to your deployment/plugins folder.

**/deploy**

```
/platforms
/plugins
icudt54.dll
icuin54.dll
icuuc54.dll
app.exe
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libssp-0.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
```

**/deploy/platforms**

```
qwindows.dll
```

**/deploy/plugins/imageformats**

```
qjpeg.dll
```

### Windeployqt

You can find windeployqt.exe in your Qt/qt-ver/qt-ver/bin folder. Windeployqt requires that your Qt/qt-ver/qt-ver/bin and mingw64/bin folder be in your User or System Path variable to work properly.

To use windeployqt, open a command window and change to your application deploy directory. The syntax for running it can be found at [Qt Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool). You'll probably want to run it as follows:

```
windeployqt.exe app.exe
```

Windeployqt (Qt 5.4.1) will copy your imageformats and iconengines plugin folders to your application deploy directory level instead of inside a plugins folder. This is the correct location, as it alters where Qt looks for these folders.

### Troubleshooting

You can test to see if you have the correct files by running your application on a computer that doesn't have the Qt development library installed and in the path. If you get no errors on your application startup, you'll know that Qt found the dependencies it needed, and you can package your application for distribution.

If you are getting errors, refer to the [Tripleboot deployment guide](http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=138). You can also try using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what dependencies your application attempts to load when it gives a dependency-missing error.

### Packaging

Frequently applications are distributed with an archive and/or an installer. The [Qt Installer Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/) provides a convenient way to package your Qt application for distribution as an installer executable.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer, it comes very close to what I need. I downloaded the "qt-5.3.1-x64-mingw482r4-sjlj.exe" and managed to build my reference program. However, I am not able to run it from QtCreator. When I tried to run a release version stand alone, I detected that the platforms directory with the qwindows.dll is missing. Unfortunately, I can't find it...

Comment: qwindows.dll should be located at qt-ver/plugins/platforms. Your deployment directory will have a slightly different structure, however. You will need a platforms and plugins folder in your deployment directory. The platforms folder will contain qwindows.dll and the plugins folder will contain subfolders for needed plugins that you can copy from your qt-ver/plugins directory.

Comment: Thanks, however, I already knew how to deploy since I have done this successfully for standard MinGW 32bit Qt. It seems like the plugins/platforms directory is missing in "qt-5.3.1-x64-mingw482r4-sjlj.exe".

Comment: That's strange. I just ran the setup and it copied plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll to the right place. It may be that your install didn't copy those files for some reason. You should be able to get the qwindows.dll and any other dlls you're missing from the "qt-5.3.1-x64-mingw482r4-sjlj.7z" download at Qt-x64. I checked and qwindows.dll is in the 7z archive. I've also hosted it for your convenience. http://www.andrewdolby.com/downloads/qwindows.7z

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is no longer active

Comment: The project got renamed/moved to a different location: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/. I'll edit the link in the answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can install MSYS2, which includes a package manager and prebuilt versions of load of packages including Qt which you can also use outside of the MSYS2 environment with e.g. Qt Creator (which is also in the repositories by the way).

Installation is easy:

1. Download the installer from [the web page](http://msys2.github.io/).
2. Open the MSYS2 command prompt and install Qt:

   pacman -Sy mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-qt5
3. Qt's qmake is installed in `<msys2>/mingw{64,32}/bin` and accessible from the respective command prompts.

In the same way you can install hundreds of other libraries and tools you might need for your development.

As for the rest of application deployment, I refer you to [the Qt project wiki page on Windows deployment](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploying_Windows_Applications).

Comment: If you do go down the MSYS2 route you can ignore the Qt On/Off-line installers that Qt itself offers you - and get a lot of extra libraries that you are likely to want - especially if you are coding an application for multiple OSes like Linux. If you are familiar with a \*nix OS the file system installed in, say `C:\msys64` will be quite recognisable... - and thank you @rubenvb for all the work you have done in developing a system to enable FOSS projects on Windows...