# What does TDM stand for in "TDM-gcc"?

Tags: gcc, tdm-mingw

I have searched for this for many site and failed. But what does TDM stand for in "TDM-gcc"?  It confuses me when I want to choose gcc as the compiler.  So, what's the difference? Should I choose TDM or NON-TDM?  Or is TDM only for minGW　on Windows platform?

The official TDM-gcc site don't even explain it...

Comment: [Twilight Dragon Media](http://www.tdragon.net/)? What's the OS you're using? What's your target OS? Yes TDM-GCC is only for Windows and on *nix you've to use GCC.

Comment: Windows MinGW, no cross-compile.

Comment: OK. I see. It's the company name.  I thought it is a feature name.. sigh..  I didn't notice the web site URL contains "dragon"...

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you want to put it as an answer? Or if  not, I would just close the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TDM-GCC is a GCC distribution on Windows. TDM stands for [Twilight Dragon Media](http://www.tdragon.net/), the project's name.

Since you want GCC on Windows, you've 3 popular options

1. [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)
2. [MinGW](http://mingw.sourceforge.net/)
3. [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)

Also choose the right exception and threading model. Details: [What is difference between sjlj vs dwarf vs seh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15670169/183120) and [mingw-w64 threads: posix vs win32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17242516/183120).

If you not only want GCC but also a Unix-like shell with all the bin, core and findutils, you may use [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) or the lighter [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/). I personally prefer the latter; it also [has a package manager](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/) and you get frequent updates for the packages installed.

Comment: Is there a package for Windows based on GCC 7.1 with OpenMP support?

Comment: All three should have OpenMP support. I tried with option 1 (Windows 10, GCC 7.1 from mingw-w64) and it does support it; make sure you add `-fopenmp` and include `omp.h`.

Comment: Where do I download the binary files of MinGW-W64 (Latest version with GCC 7.1)? On their download page they link to Arch Page which only has files for user compilation. Are there binary files?

Comment: Yeah, mingw-w64 comes in a variety of forms. [mingw-builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) is one good place to get binary packages, both as archives and installer. Read [TDM's quriks page](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/quirks) for details on the variants you'd see based on bit width, threading and exception mechanisms; usually I go for 32-bit, posix and dwarf builds.

Comment: How can I know which ones will support OpenMP? Will a DLL compiled with OpenMP compiled with GCC be able to work on any Windows?

Comment: I think all of them do. I _think_ [OpenMP support is from Windows 2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support) onwards. But hey, why don't you search it yourself before asking. These details are trivial to find on the internet. Also finding it yourself will lead to you getting more answers than asking pointed questions which were answered long back.