# What is the difference between MinGW SEH and MinGW SJLJ?

Tags: c++, c, qt, mingw

I am just starting to learn C and installing now QT x64 (form here: http://tver-soft.org/qt64). I have two options to install: `MinGW 4.9.2 SEH` or `MinGW 4.9.2 SJLJ`. 

**Question:** Which is better to install and why?

*I read [What is difference between sjlj vs dwarf vs seh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670169/what-is-difference-between-sjlj-vs-dwarf-vs-seh) and https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit#Exception_handling:_SJLJ.2C_DWARF.2C_and_SEH but understand nothing (new to C and compiller languages).*

Comment: To the people who are voting to close this, this is a perfectly reasonable thing for a new programmer to get confused about.  The differences between the 2 versions of MinGW are based entirely on concepts that a new user would not understand.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

SJLJ and SEH are two different exception handling systems.

For the specific differences, the resources you've already seen cover everything.

However, as for which one is *better* to install, <s>go with **SJLJ** unless you know that you need SEH.</s>

**2019 Update:** On modern systems, there's no reason to use SJLJ, so the advice above should probably be flipped. SEH is more common now. Ultimately though, it doesn't really matter, since it's easy to switch between the two.

#### SJLJ

SJLJ is more widely supported across architectures, and is more robust. Also, SJLJ exceptions can be thrown *through* libraries that use other exception handling systems, including C libraries. However, it has a performance penalty.

#### SEH

SEH is much more efficient (no performance penalty), but unfortunately is not well-supported. SEH exceptions will cause bad things to happen when thrown through libraries that do not also use SEH.

As far as your code is concerned, there are no real differences. You can always switch compilers later if you need to.

Comment: More explanation -- While not normally used in C code, exceptions are a way to handle errors without continually checking return codes. This is common in C++ and most object oriented languages. When an error is encountered an exception type is "thrown" and then caught by some other code. In C++ this is handled is an "implementation" issue, which means that it's not a standard, so different compilers can do it differently. The problem arises when different parts of a program (ie. libraries) implement exceptions differently.

Comment: @nategoose _"This is common in C++ and most object oriented languages."_ And not only there, even functional and (yes!) logic programming languages have exceptions. It's where we bolt-on a facility to make it easy for the programmer to handle those "exceptional conditions" that need to be punted to some part that can actually handle them.

Answer (score 19):

I discovered one difference between SJLJ and SEH exception handling in MinGW-w64: C signal handlers set by signal() function do not work in SJLJ version as soon as at least one try{} block gets executed at the run time. Since this issue does not seem to be described anywhere, I am putting it here for the record.

The following example (test_signals.cpp) demonstrates this.

```
// This sample demonstrates how try {} block disables handler set by signal()
// on MinGW-w64 with GCC SJLJ build
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

int izero = 0;

static void SIGWntHandler (int signum)//sub_code)
{
  std::cout << "In signal handler, signum = " << signum << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Now exiting..." << std::endl;
  std::exit(1);
}

int main (void)
{
  std::cout << "Entered main(), arming signal handler..." << std::endl;
  if (signal (SIGSEGV, (void(*)(int))SIGWntHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    std::cout << "signal(OSD::SetSignal) error\n";
  if (signal (SIGFPE, (void(*)(int))SIGWntHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    std::cout << "signal(OSD::SetSignal) error\n";
  if (signal (SIGILL, (void(*)(int))SIGWntHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    std::cout << "signal(OSD::SetSignal) error\n";

  // this try block disables signal handler...
  try { std::cout << "In try block" << std::endl; } catch(char*) {}

  std::cout << "Doing bad things to cause signal..." << std::endl;
  izero = 1 / izero; // cause integer division by zero
  char* ptrnull = 0;
  ptrnull[0] = '\0'; // cause access violation

  std::cout << "We are too lucky..." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Builds with:

```
g++ test_signals.cpp -o test_signals.exe
```

The expected output is:

```
Entered main(), arming signal handler...
In try block
Doing bad things to cause signal...
In signal handler, signum = 8
Now exiting...
```

The actual output when I build with MigGW-w64 SJLJ variant is:

```
Entered main(), arming signal handler...
In try block
Doing bad things to cause signal...
```

The application gets terminated silently after some delay. That is, signal handler does not get called. If try{} block is commented out, signal handler gets called properly.

When using MinGW-w64 SEH variant, it behaves as expected (signal handler gets called).

I do not have clear idea of why this problem occurs, thus will be grateful if someone can give an explanation.

Comment: you are probably better off asking on MinGW forum/ML. There is also a possibility that this is fixed in 2022 (5 years later).