# Getting linking error in mingw c++

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, dynamic-linking, mingw-w64

[image]

I have an error while running my c++ code using mingw in windows 10.
The error is something like this : the procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library ----a.exe

I have no idea how to resolve that. I tried to google it but i could not find any solution.

**Edit 1:** I noticed that programs in a particular folder are not working. For other folders it is working fine.

**Edit 2:** I reinstalled MingW. But I am getting the error whenever i am using string data type in c++. [image: Modified screenshot; Error changed]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for. One of the answers there says to use `g++` instead of `gcc`, although how `gcc` compiles C++ source at all is a mystery.

Comment: I am using g++ to compile and the solution is not provided in the link.

Answer (score -1):

I think it might have something to do with different exception handling across your code and maybe some libraries that you use.

**It may be caused by using different compiler** (even different version of MinGW).
Here is a nice explanation of differences between two:
[What is difference between sjlj vs dwarf vs seh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670169/what-is-difference-between-sjlj-vs-dwarf-vs-seh)

I remember having similar issue when using libraries compiled using different MinGW.

Answer (score -3):

Try just a hello world function:

```
int main(){
}
```

If such code still gets an "entry point cannot be loaded" error, and if you see a.exe in the linkage, move your G++ path a bit front of your system %PATH%, maybe the first one, and try again.