# robotgo for windows 10 - fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: go

If I want to run any code with robotgo under windows 10 I get following error:

```
# github.com/go-vgo/robotgo
In file included from ./bitmap/../base/str_io_c.h:2:0,
                 from ./bitmap/goBitmap.h:17,
                 from ..\go\src\github.com\go-vgo\robotgo\robotgo.go:45:
./bitmap/../base/zlib_util_c.h:2:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

my PATH variables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTXBB.png

Followed the installation and looked through the issues.

https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo#installation

Someone had a similar error here: https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo/issues/100

But their fix "*Solved, should change gcc compiler in the %PATH%*" did not work for me.

```
import (
    "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"
)

func main() {
    robotgo.ScrollMouse(10, "up")
    robotgo.MouseClick("left", true)
    robotgo.MoveMouseSmooth(100, 200, 1.0, 100.0)
}
```

Comment: Any fix for this?

Comment: @Jonathan Beaudoin, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72424179/9935654)

Answer (score 2):

I try this one below and worked for me 
https://github.com/lowkey42/MagnumOpus/wiki/TDM-GCC-Mingw64-Installation#zlib-x64

**download** ZLIB x64 from this [link](https://github.com/lowkey42/MagnumOpus/wiki/TDM-GCC-Mingw64-Installation#zlib-x64)

> copy _\zlib\bin to \TDM\bin 
> copy _\zlib\bin to \Git\bin 
> copy \zlib\include to \TDM\include 
> copy \zlib\lib to \TDM\lib

Comment: this fixed the problem for me once i found zlib-1.2.5-bin-x64.zip and copied  zlib.h to my mingw64 directory

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: ignore bitmap.go

Your code doesn't use `bitmap` so you don't need to compile this file, and then you will not encounter this error.

put `//go:build ignore` to [bitmap.go](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo/blob/c466829/bitmap.go)

```
//go:build ignore     // 

// ...
//#include "screen/goScreen.h"
#include "bitmap/goBitmap.h"
*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/vcaesar/tt"
)
// ...
```

### Solution2: install MinGW-W64.{gcc, g++}

[go to sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) to download MinGW-W64 GCC

Select what you want

- version:{..., `8.1.0`, `7.3.0`, `6.4.0`, `5.4.0`, ...}
- arch. : `x86_64`, [i686](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P6_(microarchitecture))<sup>similarly `x86`</sup>
- [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17242516/9935654): `posix`, `win32`
- [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15670169/9935654): `sjlj`, `dwarf`, `seh`

[image: download MinGW-W64]

I select [x86_64-win32-seh](https://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw-w64/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-win32/seh/x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z)<sup>8.1.0</sup>

and then

1. unzip the file.
2. copy the path: for example `C:\downloads\x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` (which contains: `gcc.exe`, `g++.exe`)
3. set go env: `CC`, `CXX`

   - `go env -w CC=C:\downloads\x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc`
   - `go env -w CXX=C:\downloads\x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++`

Finally, try to `go build` again. It should work.

---

- See more issues of build errors: [robotgo/issues/100](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo/issues/100)